# when to use atomic.Pointer[T] versus atomic.Value

Tags: go

go1.19 introduce [atomic.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer), and I noticed Some source code has moved from [atomic.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value) to [atomic.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer). (ex: [426074: sync: switch Map to use atomic.Pointer](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/426074), [422174: encoding/gob: change typeInfo.encoder type to atomic.Pointer[T]](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/422174))

So my question are:

1. If my code considers using generics, can all [atomic.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value)'s be converted to [atomic.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer)'s and what are the cases where [atomic.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value)'s should be used more?
2. Is the existence of [atomic.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value) only for compatibility reasons, should [atomic.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value) be gradually deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer more specific atomic types over `atomic.Value`.  Just as `atomic.Bool` is preferred over `atomic.Value` when working with `bool` values, `atomic.Pointer` is preferred over `atomic.Value` when working with pointers.

> If my code considers using generics, can all atomic.Value's be converted to atomic.Pointer's and what are the cases where atomic.Value's should be used more?

Convert from `atomic.Value` to `atomic.Pointer` when the value is a pointer.

> Is the existence of atomic.Value only for compatibility reasons, should atomic.Value be gradually deprecated?

The atomic types that are more specific than `atomic.Value` do not cover all possible types. There's still a need `atomic.Value`.

Comment: Please look at this example [426074: sync: switch Map to use atomic.Pointer](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/426074). The example previously stored a structure `readOnly{m: read.m, amended: true}`, now it stores a pointer to that structure `&readOnly{m: read.m, amended: true}`